# Here API's suggested address in backward format

Tags: here-api

Hi I've been using the following REST API:
http://autocomplete.geocoder.nxt.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?query=100%20Parramatta%20Rd&app_id=XX&app_code=XX&country=AUS

The result used to be:

```
{
    "Label": "100 Parramatta Road, AUBURN  NSW  2144",
    "Postcode": "2144",
    "State": "",
    "UnitNo": "",
    "StreetNo": "",
    "AddressLine1": "",
    "AddressLine2": "",
    "Suburb": "",
    "City": null,
    "Country": null,
    "BuildingName": null
}
```

But recently, the content of the "label" is backward:

```
{
     "Label": "Australia, NSW, Croydon, 100 Parramatta Rd",
     "Postcode": "2132",
     "State": "NSW",
     "UnitNo": "",
     "StreetNo": "100",
     "AddressLine1": "Parramatta Rd",
     "AddressLine2": null,
     "Suburb": "Croydon",
     "City": "Sydney",
     "Country": "Australia",
     "BuildingName": null
}
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks :)

Edited to add a more obvious question:

What should I do to make the label looks like the first one again? I want it to be "100 Parramatta Road, AUBURN NSW 2144", instead of "Australia, NSW, Croydon, 100 Parramatta Rd"

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should be more clear. What should I do to make the label looks like the first one again?

I want it to be "100 Parramatta Road, AUBURN  NSW  2144",
instead of "Australia, NSW, Croydon, 100 Parramatta Rd"

Comment: See my answer below. You should probably also mention (and tag) the programming language you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what the API you are querying is outputting, then there's not really much you can do about it, unless it's somehow configurable via your API call. Your best bet would be consulting the API documentation.

That being said, if you only need `"Australia, NSW, Croydon, 100 Parramatta Rd"` to be `"100 Parramatta Rd, Croydon, NSW, Australia"` instead, you can try splitting the string by `,` and then reversing it.

```
// the code below is in C#
var reverseLabel = string.Join(", ", result.Label.Split(',').Reverse());
```